# Convex polyhedron given its vertices

Tags: general-topology, geometry, polyhedra

Given a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it true that there is (at most) one convex polyhedron with such points as vertices? I haven't been able to find a counter-example yet but I'm not sure whether this is true or false either. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The magic phrase you're looking for is [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

Comment: The intersection of an arbitrary number of convex sets is convex, so we can define the notion of a smallest convex set containing a given set. This is one definition of the convex hull. By definition it is unique. Also, if the set of points is not finite (for example, it may be the set of points of unit length) the resulting set may not be a polyhedron.